# sort array and remove duplicates in specific columns Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to remove duplicates rows in col 0 of an array in such a way that only the max values in col 1 remain. Data is tab delimited. There are 16 columns.

```
sample1_EGFR_19 53  exon19 ...
sample1_EGFR_19 12      exon20 ...
sample2_EGFR_19 20      exon19 ...
sample3_EGFR_20 65      exon20 ...
sample2_EGFR_19 25      exon12 ...
sample1_EGFR_20 12      exon20 ...
sample3_EGFR_20 125 exon20 ...
```

Desired output:

```
sample1_EGFR_19 53      exon19 ...
sample1_EGFR_20 12      exon20 ...
sample2_EGFR_19 25      exon12 ...
sample3_EGFR_20 125 exon20 ...
```

I've started with tab delimited text files that I split and populated an array.  Then i use a hash and sort by keys. The final output I get the data correctly sorted, however, the duplicates are not removed. How do I remove lines that are now blank in the first column? Thanks

```
sample1_EGFR_19 53 exon19 ...
                 12 exon20 ...
 sample2_EGFR_19 25 exon12 ...
                 20 exon19 ...
 sample3 EGFR_20 125 exon20 ...
                 65 exon20 ...
 sample1 EGFR_20 12 exon20 ...
```

Please suggest a straight forward method to accomplish his. Thanks

Here is the code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use List::Util 'first';
use Data::Dumper;

my $filename        = "/data/Test/output.txt";
my $output_filename = "/data/Test/output_changed.txt";

my @resultarray;
my @sorted;

open( TXT2, "$filename" );
while ( <TXT2> ) {
    push( @resultarray, $_ );
}
close( TXT2 );

foreach ( @resultarray ) {
    chop( $_ );
}

foreach ( @resultarray ) {
    print( $_);
    chomp( $_ );
    my ( $key, $val ) = split /\t/, $_, 2;
    push @{ $result_hash{$key} }, $val;
}

foreach ( sort { $result_hash{$a} <=> $result_hash{$b} } keys %result_hash ) {
    push( @final_array, $_ . "\t" . join "\t", @{ $result_hash{$_} } );
}

undef %{result_hash};

foreach ( @final_array ) {
    chomp( $_ );
    print( $_);
}

for ( 0 .. @final_array - 1 ) {

    my $myuniquearray = $final_array[$_];
    open( MYFILE, ">>$output_filename" );    ##opens files with header and adds the rest of the lines.

    print MYFILE $myuniquearray . "\n";
    close( MYFILE );
}
```

Comment: `push(@resultarray, @linearray)` : You probably want `push(@resultarray, \@linearray)` or else `@resultarray` will be 1D ( and not 2D)

Comment: printed out in final output: ARRAY(0x1c3cf00)
ARRAY(0x1c98708)
ARRAY(0x1c289c8)
ARRAY(0x1b0e120)
ARRAY(0x1b0e090)
ARRAY(0x1b0e198)
ARRAY(0x1b0e1b0)

Comment: I think you could do this also by storing the lines in a hash with field 0 on each line as the key and the array reference as the value. Then, update the hash only if key is not present, or if field 1 is greater than the current value of field 1. Then after you have read the file only the correct rows will be present in the hash

Comment: @ Hakon. i've tried your method and updated the code above. Please suggest how to get finish the code that it removes rows that are now blank in the first column. thanks

Comment: i take it back ...the method i used doesn't sort by the second column. so still need help with sorting by the second column and then removing the duplicates.  Could you please come up with code examples. thanks

Comment: can't get it to work. please help.

Comment: Is there really a mixture of spaces and underscores after `sample1` etc. at the start of each line?

Comment: The layout of your code is dreadful, making it very difficult to read. You are welcome to make your own life as hard as you like, but this is very impolite when you are asking for free help and advice from strangers.

Comment: Sorry, I've improved the readability of the code. thanks

Comment: Your example data is space-delimited, not tab-delimited. Please modify your question to clarify which it is.

Comment: I did the best I could to insert tabs in the original data set. I feel like I'm being discouraged from asking questions on this forum. This is the last time I will ask for help here.  If you don't want to help don't, but there is no need to belittle any one because they are not as good a programmer as you are.

Comment: We aren't trying to belittle you, it's just very difficult to answer questions when the examples aren't consistent with the description of the problem. It's like pulling into the shop with a car other than the one you want them to fix (or no car at all). We want to help, but you have to meet us halfway.

Comment: @mwp is <>; the same as while (<>){ print; } ? thanks

Comment: @user3781528 `<>` means "read lines from stdin or the filename given by ARGV[0]" (roughly) and can be used in a while-loop or in expressions like `my @lines = <>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward UNIX one-liner. Why the requirement to write it in Perl?

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2rn /data/Test/output.txt | awk '!seen[$1]++' | tee /data/Test/output_changed.txt
sample1_EGFR_19 53  exon19  ...
sample1_EGFR_20 12  exon20  ...
sample2_EGFR_19 25  exon12  ...
sample3_EGFR_20 125 exon20  ...
```

This sorts it by the first column ascending and by the second column descending and numeric, then uses `awk` to select the first line from each group. If that `awk` statement is too confusing, it has the same function as `awk 'x != $1 { print; x = $1 }'`. (`tee` writes the lines to the file **and** displays the output to the terminal.)

If you really must use Perl, here's a simple solution to the described problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub sort_func {
  # sort by the first col asc and then by the second col desc and numeric
  $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] || $b->[1] <=> $a->[1]
}

my %seen;
print
  map join("\t", @$_),     # re-join the fields with tabs into the original line
  grep !$seen{$_->[0]}++,  # select the first line of each sorted group
  sort sort_func           # sort lines using the above sort function
  map [split /\t/, $_, 3], # split by tabs so we can sort by the first two fields
  <>;                      # read lines from stdin or the filename given by ARGV[0]
```

Mark the file executable and use it like so:

```
./sortlines.pl /data/Test/output.txt >/data/Test/output_changed.txt
```